# How to resize selection area of Radiobutton and Checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

[image]

```
v = Radiobutton(root,text="Male" , height=50)
v.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

How to change selection area size for `Checkbutton` and `Radiobutton`?

Comment: Are you talking about the size of check box?

Comment: Yes. Only Indicator size(Please refer red marked area). BTW  I took that screen shot from web for demonstration. I need to change indicator size in winform

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly change the size of the box. However, you can supply your own images for the checked and unchecked state. The images you pick can be any images you want, and can be any size you want.

You can define the unselected and selected images with the `image` and `selectimage` attributes of the widget.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try